# I'm trying to vertically align my bootstrap form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The other answers didn't quit help, im trying to center the form inputs/labels.

Heres my actual code

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="FormCol">
                <h2 class="formTitle">Let Us Find the Fastest Internet in Your Area!</h2>
                <form class="form-inline" id="contactForm">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label for="pnumber">Phone Number</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="pnumber" name="pnumber" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label for="Zip">Zip</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="Zip" name="Zip" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Heres an image of the problem 
[image]

Comment: Please don't ask a new question if your previous one doesn't get answers you like; edit it instead, request clarification from the answers, and/or offer a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the columns to be 12 instead of six, that's why you got it in 2 columns.

HTML:

```
            <form class="form-inline" id="contactForm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" type="text" />
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" type="text" />
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="pnumber">Phone Number</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="pnumber" name="pnumber" type="text" />
                    </div>
              </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text" />
                    </div>
              </div>
                  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="Zip">Zip</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="Zip" name="Zip" type="text" />
                </div>
               </div>
            </form>
```